# Ubuntu vsftpd server error: 500 OOPS: could not read chroot() list file:/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, vsftpd

I configured an FTP server for Ubuntu using vsftpd. However, I can't access the server.

```
Status: Connecting to IP
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 (vsFTPd 2.3.2)
Command:    USER userhere
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Command:    PASS ***************
Response:   500 OOPS: could not read chroot() list file:/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
Error:  Critical error
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

**EDIT**

The problem was solved ! Comment the line `chroot_list_enable=YES`

Comment: I'd say this is more like disabling the feature, it's not fixing the problem. But it doesn't matter if your FTP server now do what you want it to :-)    About the answer, instead of editing your main post, mark the answer you used as being the answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Quick fix would be to disable chroot_list_enable switch in your conf file for Vsftpd( usually in /etc/vsftpd.conf)

```
#chroot_list_enable=YES
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
```

Comment out mentioned line above and see it helps or not.

Answer (score 1):

you must apply below command,

`setsebool -P ftp_home_dir on`

`setsebool -P allow_ftpd_full_access=1`

I solved this method.